# Both nVidia GPU and Intel Graphics running on Gigabyte g1sniper-b5 motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

Does this motherboard supports "crossfiring" the two graphics adapters? I just wanna use both hdmi ports, one provided by the Intel CPU (Intel Graphics) and the nVidia one.

Is this possible?

Sorry if something I said is not right, those are from my limited knowledge :)

Comment: Not familar with the specific chipset or what Gigabyte would call it, but on my asus board, the "iGPU Multi-Monitor" setting did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both nVidia GPU and Intel graphics running on Gigabyte g1sniper-b5
>   motherboard
>
> Does this motherboard supports "crossfiring" the two graphics adapters?

No. Crossfire only works between two similar AMD graphics cards.
The same is true for Nvidia GPU's, though they call it differently (SLI).

When you crossfire one of the graphics cards **disables** its outputs and it just acts as a calculating unit. It does not grant more outputs. It just speeds out the calculations which are then outputted by the primary card.

> I just wanna use both HDMI ports, one provided by the Intel CPU (Intel
>   Graphics) and the nVidia one.

Now that is not a problem. YOu can use two (or more) graphics cards ah the same time. Simply install the drivers for them and they should be good to go.

Exceptions:

- Windows 98, windows XP, windows 95 and similar old operating system only supported one graphics driver. At best those supported several identical cards.
- Some switchable graphics used on laptops. These tend to do 'interesting' things.